# How to get contents of nested tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

How can I use BeautifullSoup to get to the number before the closing span tag?

```
<span class="count">
<i class="icon-user"></i>
30.5K </span>
```

I can use:

```
usercount=soup.findAll('span',{'class':'count'})
```

but not:

```
usercount=soup.findAll('i',{'class':'count'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The text you're after is the text node after the `<i>` in the `<span>`:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''
    <span class="count">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    30.5K </span>
''')

usercount = soup.find('span', class_='count').find('i').next.strip()
```