# How to remove content in nested tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, nested, beautifulsoup

How to remove content in nested tags with `BeautifulSoup`? These posts showed the reverse to retrieve the content in nested tags: [How to get contents of nested tag using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982406/how-to-get-contents-of-nested-tag-using-beautifulsoup), and [BeautifulSoup: How do I extract all the <li>s from a list of <ul>s that contains some nested <ul>s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362981/beautifulsoup-how-do-i-extract-all-the-lis-from-a-list-of-uls-that-contains)

I have tried `.text` but it only removes the tags

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> html = "<foo>Something something <bar> blah blah</bar> something</foo>"
>>> bs(html).find_all('foo')[0]
<foo>Something something <bar> blah blah</bar> something else</foo>
>>> bs(html).find_all('foo')[0].text
u'Something something  blah blah something else'
```

Desired output:

> Something something  something else

Comment: So... in this example you'd like to remove the contents of `bar`?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a "else" in the second line of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for `bs4.element.NavigableString` on children:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import bs4
html = "<foo>Something something <bar> blah blah</bar> something <bar2>GONE!</bar2> else</foo>"
def get_only_text(elem):
    for item in elem.children:
        if isinstance(item,bs4.element.NavigableString):
            yield item

print ''.join(get_only_text(bs(html).find_all('foo')[0]))
```

Output;

```
Something something  something  else
```

Answer (score 3):

Eg.

```
body = bs(html)
for tag in body.find_all('bar'):
    tag.replace_with('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple method, `soup.body.clear()`  or `soup.tag.clear()`

let's say you want to clear the content in `<table></table>` and add a new pandas dataframe; later you can use this clear method to easily update your tables in an html file for your webpage instead of flask/django:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import bs4
```

I want to convert a 1.2million row .csv into a DataFrame, then into a HTML table,
        and then add it to my webpage's html syntax. Later I want to easily 
        update the data whenever the csv gets updated by simply switching a variable

```
    bizcsv = read_csv("business.csv")
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(bizcsv)
    dfhtml = dframe.to_html #convert DataFrame to table, HTML format
    dfhtml_update = dfhtml_html.strip('<table border="1" class="dataframe">, </table>')
    """use dfhtml_update later to update your table without the <table> tags,
    the <table> is easy for BS to select & clear!"""

    #A small function to unescape (&lt; to <) the tags back into HTML format
    def unescape(s):
        s = s.replace("&lt;", "<")
        s = s.replace("&gt;", ">")
        # this has to be last:
        s = s.replace("&amp;", "&")
        return s

    with open("page.html") as page:  #return to here when updating
        txt = page.read()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt, features="lxml")
        soup.body.append(dfhtml) #adds table to <body>
        with open("page.html", "w") as outf:
            outf.write(unescape(str(soup))) #writes to page.html

    """lets say you want to make seamless table updates to your 
    webpage instead of using flask or django x_x; return to with open function"""
    soup.table.clear()  #clears everything in <table></table>
    soup.table.append(dfhtml_update)
    with open("page.html", "w") as outf:
        outf.write(unescape(str(soup)))
```

I'm a newbie, but after tons of searching I just combined a bunch of fundamental teachings from the documentation...Kind of bloated, but so is working with literally billions of cells of data. This works for me

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is kill a tag (bar) along with the content (blah blah). here is the code for you along with explanation

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = "<foo>Something something <bar> blah blah</bar> something</foo>"
soup = bs(html) # this is the soup
#lets find all bars and remove it along with content. decompose does it. 
for bar in soup.find_all('bar'):
 bar.decompose() 
print(soup) # returns " <html><body><foo>Something something    something</foo></body></html>"
# now lets extract the text with .text
print(soup.text)
```