# Clean out tags bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to retrieve just the info in p tags i dont want anything else.How can I do this? This is what I did so far. I am getting additional information which I dont need

```
 page = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jun/30/mexican- 
woman-117-years-old-dies-birth-certificate')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#soup.i.decompose()

content_list = soup.find('body')
# Pull text from all instances of <p> tag within BodyText div
content_list_items = content_list.find_all('p')    

for content_list in content_list_items:
    print(content_list.prettify())
```

Comment: you mean removing all tags in `p` but remain all the text?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'additional information' that you get but don't need.
You can get the plain text without any HTML tags by using the *text* attribute, like this: content_list.text. If that is not what you want please specify your question: what would be the result you expect?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

page = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jun/30/mexican-woman-117-years-old-dies-birth-certificate')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

content_list_items = soup.body.find_all('p')    

for content_list in content_list_items:
    txt = content_list if type(content_list) == NavigableString else content_list.text
    print(txt)
```

**EDIT**

So, based on this solution ([How to remove content in nested tags with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757377/how-to-remove-content-in-nested-tags-with-beautifulsoup?rq=1)) you can iterate the children and pick only those that are of type NavigableString. For your particular example this will, however, also remove links in anchor tags, e.g. the sentence: *A 117-year-old woman in City finally received her birth certificate ...* whereas the original sentence was *A 117-year-old woman in **Mexico** City finally received her birth certificate ...*

```
content_list_items = soup.body.find_all('p')

for content_list in content_list_items:
    for child in content_list.children:
        if type(child) == NavigableString:
            print(child.strip())
```

Comment: So, what I Mean is that inside p tags there are more tags, but I want to delete all tags that come inside the p tags and only display info for p tags